# como hacer un calendario horizontal en un rango de fechas en php?

Tags: php

necesito hacer un calendario de eventos pero que sea horizontal, he visto varios tutoriales de hacer un calendario de eventos pero solo por mes y yo necesito uno que sea de varios meses es por eso que necesito que el calendario sea horizontal parecido a este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he hecho un codigo que me genera un calendario por año,muy parecido al de la imagen pero, lo malo es que yo necesito que el calendario este en un rango de fechas que pueden ser del mismo año como de diferente año, es aqui donde me bloque y nose como hacerlo.

les paso el codigo aunq como dijo no es lo quiero

```
<?php 


date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

setlocale( LC_TIME, 'spanish' );

$year=isset( $_GET[ 'chooseYear' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'chooseYear' ] : " ";
//echo $year;
$meses=['ENERO','FEBRERO','MARZO','ABRIL','MAYO','JUNIO','JULIO','AGOSTO','SETIEMBRE','OCTUBRE','NOVIEMBRE','DICIEMBRE'];
//$month='2017-01';
    if ($year!=" ") {
        for ($j=1; $j <=12 ; $j++) { 
        for ( $i=1;$i<=date( 't', strtotime( $year."-".$j ) );$i++ ) {
        //echo $year."-".$i."/";
        $calendar[$j][$i]="<input type='checkbox'>";

        if ((($year % 4 == 0) && (($year % 100 != 0) || ($year % 400 == 0))) && $j==2) {
            $calendar[$j][30]=" ";
            $calendar[$j][31]=" ";
        }

        else if($j==2) {
            $calendar[$j][29]=" ";
            $calendar[$j][30]=" ";
            $calendar[$j][31]=" ";
        }
        if ($j==4 || $j==6 || $j==9 || $j==11) {
            $calendar[$j][31]=" ";
        }

        }
    }
    }else{
        echo "Seleccione anio";
    }
    //var_dump($calendar);
    //echo count($calendar[1]);
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ASISITENCIA TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <br><br>
        <form action="" method="get">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
            <select name="chooseYear" id="" class="form-control">
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                <option value="2021">2021</option>
            </select>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-3">  
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>  
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: gray;color: white">
                    <th>MES/AÑO</th>
                    <th colspan="31" style="text-align: center;">DIA</th>                   
                    <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">DOSIS MENSUAL</th>              
                </tr>
                <tr style="font-size: 12px">
                    <th></th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <th>9</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                    <th>11</th>
                    <th>12</th>
                    <th>13</th>
                    <th>14</th>
                    <th>15</th>
                    <th>16</th>
                    <th>17</th>
                    <th>18</th>
                    <th>19</th>
                    <th>20</th>
                    <th>21</th>
                    <th>22</th>
                    <th>23</th>
                    <th>24</th>
                    <th>25</th>
                    <th>26</th>
                    <th>27</th>
                    <th>28</th>
                    <th>29</th>
                    <th>30</th>
                    <th>31</th>
                    <th>Mensual</th>
                    <th>Acumulado</th>
                    <th>Faltas</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php if ($year!=" ") { ?>
                    <?php for ($i=1; $i <=12 ; $i++) { ?>   
                        <tr id="fila<?php echo $i;  ?>">
                            <td><?php echo $meses[$i-1].'/'.$year?></td>
                            <?php for ($j=1; $j <=count($calendar[1]); $j++) { ?>
                            <td><?php echo $calendar[$i][$j]; ?></td>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" id="mensual<?php echo $i; ?>"> </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;" id="acumulado<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                        </tr>   
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    /*  $(document).ready(function(){


    $("#fila1 input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
        var elemento=this;
        var contador1=0;


        $("#fila1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
                contador1++;
        });
        $("#mensual1").html(contador1);
        $("#acumulado1").html(contador1);
    });

    $("#fila2 input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){

        var elemento=this;
        var contador2=0;


        $("#fila2 input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
                contador2++;
        });
        $("#mensual2").html(contador2);
        var suma=contador1+contador2;
        $("#acumulado2").html(suma);
    });
});*/
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a pasar a una función lo siguiente:

```
function getEventCalendar($year){
if ($year!=" ") {
    for ($j=1; $j <=12 ; $j++) { 
    for ( $i=1;$i<=date( 't', strtotime( $year."-".$j ) );$i++ ) {
    //echo $year."-".$i."/";
    $calendar[$j][$i]="<input type='checkbox'>";

    if ((($year % 4 == 0) && (($year % 100 != 0) || ($year % 400 == 0))) && $j==2) {
        $calendar[$j][30]=" ";
        $calendar[$j][31]=" ";
    }

    else if($j==2) {
        $calendar[$j][29]=" ";
        $calendar[$j][30]=" ";
        $calendar[$j][31]=" ";
    }
    if ($j==4 || $j==6 || $j==9 || $j==11) {
        $calendar[$j][31]=" ";
    }

    }
}
}else{
    echo "Seleccione anio";
}
return $calendar;
}
```

De este modo solo con que llames a la función getEventCalendar(2017) podrás tener en una variable todo el calendario de ese año:

```
$annio2017 = getEventCalendar(2017);
$annio2016 = getEventCalendar(2016);
```

Y si ahora solo quieres x meses, sabes que $annio2017 y $annio2016 son arays de arrays, por lo que poniendo:

```
$annio2017[0] // tendrías enero
$annio2017[5] // junio
```

Guarda estos meses deseados en un array:

```
$meses = array();
$meses[] = $annio2017[0];
$meses[] = $annio2017[5];
```

y luego en el bucle que imprime, has de recorrer este array.

Pega de este modo, es que los años/meses los tienes que elegir estaticamente en el código, si quieres hacer algo más dinamico, tendrías que hacer un form (como el que tienes ahora) pero con más opciones para poder elegir con más precisión, y luego con un poco de php coger los campos del formulario, procesar que meses de que años pide, y seleccionar esos en concreto.

Espero haber podido ayudar algo. 
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, entiendo que tu problema entonces es de lógica frente a cómo afrontar el problema:

Mi propuesta es la siguiente:

1. Tienes un campo de fecha de inicio y de fecha de fin.
2. Tal como haces comprobando el año y el mes está bien para pintar.
3. Después de esos filtros, te queda un filtro más que sería el de comprobación de día de inicio (del primer mes) y de fin (del ultimo mes) -- los que están seleccionados en los campos del formulario --
4. Pintas los check sólo si es mayor al día de inicio y si es inferior al día de fin.

Espero ser de ayuda, saludos!!